# Programmatically upload and launch iPhone/iPad application on a device

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, automation, automated-tests

I am looking for some way to programmatically upload an iPhone/iPad application to a device through USB connection from Mac OS X and launch the application on the device. I know how to do it manually from XCode. The goal is to create test automation of an application on iPhone/iPad device/simulator. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although not necessarily programmatic, you can try using the Automator on the Mac - you can record a workflow and then replay it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode actions, such as Build and Run, are Applescript-able, and you can run Applescript scripts from another automation script (say in Python) running on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think it should work as a preliminary solution. Moreover, I have planned to use Python for the automation. So, it fits my plans. I also want to investigate how Xcode does it internally. It should have some application or plug-in that performs uploading and launching. It would be great if it’s a command line tool. 
I would vote for your answer but I am not allowed yet.